# truncate a very large float to 2 digits c++

Tags: c++, truncate

would need help understanding how I can solve this problem.

I have a float number (these are dynamic numbers, no static) whose value is, for example:

-27.8738e007

I need to truncate to 2 digits (-27.87), but I'm not succeeding.

I've tried different forms, but nothing works for that "e" in the number ...

For example:

```
float number = -27.8738e007;

int decimals = 2;
number = (roundf (number * pow (10, decimals)) / pow (10, decimals));
```

this returns -2.787383 + 008 and I need  get  -27.87

Thanks in advance

Greetings

Comment: Rounding a floating-point number to a specified number of *decimal* places rarely makes sense. Floating-point representation is (almost always) binary; a number like `1.23` can't even be represented exactly. It does make sense to round on output, but rounding internally just loses information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're not familiar with how scientific notation works.

-27.8738e007 is -278738000, or -2.787380e+08

Truncation or rounding to "n" digits generally refers to rounding a number to the given number of digits after the decimal point. This is what the code that you posted is trying to accomplish.

Of course, -278738000 rounded to two digits after the decimal point is still the same number, which is the answer you're getting.

-27.87380e+07 is 2.787380e+08

It's the same number.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: It's true. My lab/workarea/server room is in my basement. This is exactly where I am, right now.

Comment: thanks Sam, but.. how can i convert scientific notation to normal float ?

Comment: Scientific notation cannot be "converted" to anything. Scientific notation represents the value of the float or double. The value of the float or double will be exactly the same whether or not it is represented in scientific or fixed precision form. You can convert the underlying float or double to fixed precision representation by setting std::ios_base::fixed and std::ios_base::precision(), or by use the std::fixed and std::precision manipulators, when formatting the float or double value.